# Hover JQuery toggle

Tags: jquery

Good morning,

I would like to now if I can create a hover effect with JQuery. Is it possible if the user puts the mouse over an image and then it displays a toggle effect with some text? How can I do that?

At the moment, the toggle effect is working when the user "click" on the image, but I would like to create the same effect with a simple hover.

This is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#flip1").click(function(){
                $("#panel1").slideToggle("500");
            });
            $("#flip2").click(function(){
                $("#panel2").slideToggle("500");
            });
            $("#flip3").click(function(){
                $("#panel3").slideToggle("500");
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Is it possible with JQuery?

Thanks,

Regards,

Comment: why not!! change the click to hover $("#flip1").hover(

Comment: Instead of repeating the same set of code... if you can share the html we can help you to write it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#flip1").hover(function(){
      $("#panel1").stop(true).slideToggle("500");
   });
   $("#flip2").hover(function(){
      $("#panel2").stop(true).slideToggle("500");
   });
   $("#flip3").hover(function(){
      $("#panel3").stop(true).slideToggle("500");
   });
});
```

Read [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover)

You can use `data-panel` on `image` like

```
<img id="flip1" data-panel="#panel1" src="..." />
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#flip1, #flip2, #flip3").hover(function(){
      $($(this).data('panel')).stop(true).slideToggle("500");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events... [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) provides a shortcut to do it

```
$("#flip1").hover(function () {
    $("#panel1").stop(true).slideToggle("500");
});
```

or to register all handlers at once

```
$("#flip1, #flip2, #flip3").hover(function () {
    $("#panel" + this.id.replace('flip', '')).stop(true).slideToggle("500");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hover` event and register one handler using a `start with selector`, then gets its progressive and show the relative panel accordingly:

```
$("[id^=flip]").hover(function () {
    $("#panel" + this.id.replace('flip', '')).stop(true).slideToggle("500");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/C3kRp/